# NullPointerException in URL getContent

Tags: android, url, nullpointerexception

i just got a crash error in my app.The error is

```
Exception class java.lang.NullPointerException
Source method URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream()
```

and

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.net.URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(URLConnection.java:675)
at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:162)
at java.net.URL.getContent(URL.java:621)
at kostas.menu.olympiakos.nea.onListItemClick(nea.java:160)
at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:321)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the class called `"nea"` is loading some RSS with images,and the crash line is

```
 try {

 (nea.java:160) Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imagee).getContent());
                image1.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
              } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
               //log exception here
              } catch (IOException e) {
                //log exception here
              }
```

Did my app crashed because there was no image to load,or the problem is somewhere else?thanks

EDIT:
Keep on mind that:

```
List<String> imgl = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and

```
   String imagee=imgl.get(position).toString();
```

@aster:

i replaced this:

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imagee).getContent());
                image1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

with that:

```
URL url = new URL(imagee);
                InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                image1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test it easily.

Just declare variables to store intermediate result like this :

```
Url url = new Url(imagee);
InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

You'll get a line that crash with only one simple call and you will know easily what object to check or correct.

Comment: i dont get any crash result.please check my question to see what i replaced

Comment: On what line does this crash now ? You must have something wrong, some object which's not initialized the right way.